# how to set default content for emacs's scratch buffer

Tags: emacs

Is there anyway for me to set the default content of the scratch buffer in emacs?

So say, can i do something like this:

```
emacs <some option> "this is my default text" <ENTER>
```

This would open up emacs, and put "`this is my default text`" onto the buffer?

Comment: This need seems very unusual.  Could you give some details for why you need that?  Maybe you could do it better differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your .emacs file: `(setq initial-scratch-message "this is my default text")`

(Response to comment:) If you want to make it dynamic, you could run the following from the command line:  `emacs --eval "(setq initial-scratch-message \"your message\")"`

Comment: Well, I want them to by "dynamic".

Comment: That is, it should change as I change the argument.

Comment: Thanks!!! By the way, I just asked another emacs-related question, which I think you'd probably be the one to answer. Can you take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415525/echo-current-content-of-emacss-buffer-upon-closing :D