# echo current content of emacs's buffer upon closing

Tags: emacs

Is there anyway for me to configure emacs so that when I close it (`C-c`), it'd return the current content of the buffer to the shell?

Addition:
I know that `buffer-string` gives me a string containing the entire content of the currently focused buffer.
**The question is, how do I return this string back to the shell?**

Comment: Not a full answer because I don't know how to do it, but have a look at `kill-emacs-hook`.

Comment: This need seems very unusual. Could you give some details for why you need that? Maybe you could do it better differently.

Comment: @Stefan Not to be arrogant, but I'm pretty sure there's no other way. What I'm trying to do is to launch emacs from inside my program. And I want the program to know what was in the buffer when the user closes/kill emacs.

Comment: "The buffer" is kind of meaningless since there can be hundreds of buffers inside an Emacs session.

Comment: Ok, I meant the "currently-focused" buffer.

Comment: It would be relatively easy to write out the contents of the buffer to a file, which your program could read after Emacs returns. I don't know if there's a mechanism for Emacs to 'return' a value to stdout.

Comment: e.g.: `file=$(mktemp) && emacs -Q -nw $file && cat $file && rm $file`